Can I get the certified copy of my marriage certificate Apostilled (not the original)?
I have a marriage certificate issued by LA County Clerk Recorder's office and I need to get it apostilled for use in Ukraine and Ukrainian Consulate.
Can I get a certified copy from the LA County Clerk's office and Apostilled that, instead of on the original marriage certificate?
Also, is Apostille an actual stamp on the marriage certificate (or any document) or is it just an attachment?
Thanks a lot for your answers.


Can I get a certified copy from the LA County Clerk's office and Apostilled that, instead of on the original marriage certificate?

Yes.

Also, is Apostille an actual stamp on the marriage certificate (or any document) or is it just an attachment?

It is an attachment.
